# Provide compile-time constant for IFormatProvider

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a string extension method with the following signature:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseExact(this string src, string format, IFormatProvider provider = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None)
{
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error:

> Default parameter value for 'provider' must be a compile-time constant

Couldn't find anything on google and my only work around is to do this:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseExact(this string src, string format, IFormatProvider provider = null, DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None)
{
    if (provider == null)
        provider = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
}
```

Anyone know how I can set the default value of IFormatProvider in the signature? Is it even possible? IFormatProvider is an interface so I'm assuming that's where the issue lies.

Comment: The problem is not that it's an interface, it's that it's value is not available at compile-time (it's calculated at run-time), which is a requirement for default parameters. I've always approached this just like you... by using a `null` default parameter and checking for it at runtime. I'm not sure you're going to be able to take any other approach if you want to use a value that is only known at run-time (`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`).

Comment: See [Why must default method parameters be compile-time constants in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242946/why-must-default-method-parameters-be-compile-time-constants-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how I can set the default value of IFormatProvider in the signature? Is it even possible?

No. Optional arguments ("default parameters") are a modification of the language, introduced with C# 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010.

Providing a default value for a parameter does not change that method signature. In your case, there is only one method signature:

```
TryParseExact(this string src, string format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style);
```

And in the *metadata* of that method, so in the compiled assembly, the default values will be recorded. Any caller that wishes to use these default values, will get those from the metadata - and compile their values into the call site.

Because that is how it works, the default values must be compile-time constants, so they can be embedded in the metadata.

[`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.currentinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a compile-time constant, it is an object instance set by the runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In this case i advice to create several overloaded methods, and in one with less parameters set defaults inside and call another with more parameters:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseExact(this string src, string format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)
{
    //do stuff
}

public static DateTime? TryParseExact(this string src, string format)
{
    IFormatProvider provider = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
    return TryParseExact(src, format, provider, style);
}
```